# Kurento datachannel creation and management

Tags: javascript, node.js, stun, kurento, turn

I'm developing a WebRTC application based in node.js and Kurento and I want to implement a chat using datachannels.

I've seen the [browser javascript version](https://github.com/Kurento/kurento-tutorial-js/tree/master/kurento-hello-world-data-channel) and I want to integrate it in the [one to one node.js example](https://github.com/Kurento/kurento-tutorial-node/tree/master/kurento-one2one-call).

**What I have done**

1.- I've created both WebRTCEndpoints with datachannel capabilities like this: `pipeline.create('WebRtcEndpoint', {useDataChannels: true}, function(error, calleeWebRtcEndpoint) {...}`
2.- Then I've created a `<textarea>` with a `<button>` to send messages, and a `<div>` to view them.

So my question is, **what servers I have to put when I create the datachannel in the client?**  This snippet is from the browser javascript datachannel tutorial but at the start of the file we can clearly see ICE servers are ignoring in the connection creation.  Also, I don’t know how you manage them in the node.js tutorials, so I'm a bit lost here.

```
peerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection(servers, configuration);

channel = peerConnection.createDataChannel(getChannelName(), dataConstraints);

channel.onopen = onSendChannelStateChange;
channel.onclose = onSendChannelStateChange;
channel.onmessage = onMessage;`
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've discovered what was I doing wrong and now the I can send messages by datachannels.

Basically what I've done is to add `peerConnection` option to the options object.  Next that option object is passed to `WebRtcPeerSendrecv` connection method and it's done!

```
var options = {
    peerConnection: peerConnection, //Must be passed as a field in options to make DataChannels work
    localVideo : videoInput,
    remoteVideo : videoOutput,
    onicecandidate : onIceCandidate
}

webRtcPeer = kurentoUtils.WebRtcPeer.WebRtcPeerSendrecv(options, function(){...});
```

Comment: I have this but my datachannel is never connected in firefox